# Filtre layer 2 multicast packet

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, multicast, ebtables

I tried to filter layer 2 multicast packet (no IP header) generated by GOOSE protocol.

[image]

The commands below are used (ebtable and iptables) but did not work. Can anyone please give some advice?

I used ebtables because i readed that iptables can't open packet who dont have ip header (layer 3 minimum). The packet were sent from machine A to machine B (client/server software).

a. ebtables -A INPUT  -j DROP
   ebtables -A OUTPUT  -j DROP

b. iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pky-type multicast  -j DROP
   iptables -A OUTPUT -m pkttype --pky-type multicast  -j DROP

I tried  all the commands above, but i can't stop my multicast packet (DROP was just used for test purpose)

Thank you in advanced...

Answer (score 0):

For the one's who are in the same probleme in the future, i manage to resolve the probleme, first, you should now that iptables can't filter protocole who don't use ip header, so in my case, my protocole is layer 2 (like arp), the best tool for that is ebtables.

The DROP test that i already realise didn't work because i used ebatbles in a normale inerface, and this is a probleme for ebtables, he don't accept it, you should configure an bridge interface before using ebtables.

This the command i typed to creat bridge:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl stp br0 off
brctl addif br0 eno16777736
ifconfig br0 10.0.0.131 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig eno16777736 0 0.0.0.0
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1    

ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -j DROP
```

Hop this will help some one in the future